# need help in rough calculation of concurrent users

Tags: php, mysql, apache, concurrency, server-side

I will tell you about website specs for the below configuration.

- social networking site- 70%dynamic content
- Linux centos 6.6
- Apache web server
- php language

server specs x 2 (main server and sql server)

- 4 x Intel® Xeon® E5-4640 v2 2.20GHz, 20M Cache, 8.0GT/s QPI, 10 Core
- 48 x 16GB (768 GB) RDIMM, 1600MT/s, Low Volt RAM
- 4 x 300GB 15K RPM SAS 6Gbps
- for other storage = Dell Storage Direct-Attached Storage (DAS)
- network = 10 gigabit / sec

Assume that memcache / load balancer / other extra servers are there and not included in this.

(just needed rough calculation)

my question is:

1. how many concurrent users (users that will click at a same time) this platform can handle and assume that average connectivity of users will be 512 kilobit / sec.
2. concurrent users depends on which factor ? (ram>cpu>hdd is this right?)

I am not an expert , this question is for educational purpose only.

Comment: This question shouldn't be on stackoverflow.

Comment: You can test concurrency using [siege](http://linux.die.net/man/1/siege). You cannot tell by specs alone, it depends a lot on the code and a lot of other factors.

Comment: Have a look at Apache Bench for load-testing too (`ab`), it comes with Apache by default.

Comment: That's an awful lot of RAM btw. Are you sure you need that much? How many users are you expecting?

Comment: 15000-20000 concurrent users for this much ram .. my processor will be able to handle it ?

Comment: will try it.
thank you Bart Haalstra and halfer,

Comment: 15K users **concurrently** is probably approaching Facebook levels of traffic. If a page takes 0.2 sec to generate, for example, you'd be looking at (24*60*60*(1/0.2)*15000) users per day. By that stage you'd be using CDNs, and perhaps putting servers is multiple data centres. This sounds like highly premature optimisation - just get your project working on a small VPS first.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very vague.  The load that you can support will depend on the complexity of your PHP code and database design... planning (and even testing) load is a complicated topic.

You could also configure your hardware in a variety of ways which will have an impact on performance.  Which RAID system you use will depend on whether your application is read or write heavy, as will your database design.

You will also need to consider whether to use Virtualisation for backup/redundancy which adds a layer of performance overhead...

Comment: assume that website has only one page , like facebook "live feeds" = live feeds + some static content +advertisement +live chat and code is nicely written

and which RAID system should i select according to you?